Error: NG01203: No value accessor for form control name: 'name'
Someone can help me please ? I have two components Parent and Child. In Parent Component I have this formGroup and two method to get person and city.
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      person: this.fb.group({
        name: new FormControle(''),
        age: new FormControle(''),
      }),
      city: this.fb.group({ name: new FormControl('') })
    })
  }

  get person(): FormGroup {
    return this.form.get('person') as FormGroup;
  }

  get city(): FormGroup {
    return this.form.get('city') as FormGroup;
  }

I want to get Person FormGroup in Child Component like this
<app-child-component [form]="person"></app-child-component>

I have html component like this inside the child component
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="text" formControlName="name"/>
</form>

Inside component.ts child I have
@Input() form: FormGroup;

Everything is working fine, I get the following error in my console Error: NG01203: No value accessor for form control name: 'name'
If I make console.log(this.form); in child component, the form is define.

I think you are missing the form wrapper on the parent component, also we need to wrap the component inside a div with the formGroupName which specifies it belong under person form group.
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div formGroupName="person">
    <app-child [form]="person"/>
  </div>
  <div formGroupName="city">
  <input type="text" formControlName="name"/>
  </div>
</form>

Full Code:
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input type="text" formControlName="name"/>
      <input type="text" formControlName="age"/>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class Child {
  @Input() form!: FormGroup;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [Child, ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <div formGroupName="person">
        <app-child [form]="person"/>
      </div>
      <div formGroupName="city">
      <input type="text" formControlName="name"/>
      </div>
    </form>

{{form.value | json}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      person: this.fb.group({
        name: new FormControl(''),
        age: new FormControl(''),
      }),
      city: this.fb.group({ name: new FormControl('') }),
    });
  }

  get person(): FormGroup {
    return this.form.get('person') as FormGroup;
  }

  get city(): FormGroup {
    return this.form.get('city') as FormGroup;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
